# "fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory" when trying to compile C++ program using a makefile

Tags: c++, macos, boost, makefile, macos-sierra

I am trying to compile a piece of open source software called ["SPECIES
Identification of Taxonomic Mentions in Text"](http://species.jensenlab.org/). **I am on MacOS**.

I downloaded the source code (which can be found [here](http://download.jensenlab.org/species_tagger.tar.gz)), moved into the directory and used the command `make` to compile. This is the error returned:

```
g++ -fpic -pthread -Wall -O3 -o organisms organisms.cxx -lm -lboost_regex
In file included from batch_tagger.h:5:0,
                 from organisms.cxx:3:
tagger.h:7:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [organisms] Error 1
```

I installed the **C++ boost library** using `brew install boost`and tried the above steps again (*it did not work*).

I tried dropping the boost directory into the directory containing the source code (*it did not work*).

**Any suggestions/help?**

Comment: Does it(this software) have a readme or a suggestion on how to build?

Comment: Unfortunately it is very bare bones. Here is an excerpt: "To execute the SPECIES, ORGANISMS taggers, simply run the binary executable obtained from compiling the source code with one command-line argument". You can see that it is not explained how to properly compile with boost. I imagine it is simple and that is why it is left out, but unfortunately I know little about C++/C++ libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler where to find boost headers.

You need to use the include path option to specify where the boost headers can be find, use `-I/path/to/boost/include`.

Then include the file using `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` from your code.

Comment: Sorry, but I really do not know much about C++/C++ libraries. Where do I specify the path exactly?

Comment: Okay. I tried adding `-I /path/to/boost/` in my compile command (which is now `g++ -I /path/to/boost/ -fpic -pthread -Wall -O3 -o organisms organisms.cxx -lm -lboost_regex`) but I still get an error?

Comment: @JohnG: I doubt boost is installed in `/path/to/boost/include` on your machine. This was an example, you must find where boost header files are located and replace `path/to/boost/include` ("path to boost include folder") with the path where `boost/regex.hpp` can be found. Also note there is no space between `-I` and the path. For instance, on my machine, I would need to specify `-I/usr/include` (which would be useless, as /usr/include is used by default) because `regex.hpp` is located in `/usr/include/boost/regex.hpp`

Comment: My apologies. When I said /path/to/boost/ I was also using it as an example. Here is the new call to the compiler: `g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_64_0  -fpic -pthread -Wall -O3 -o organisms organisms.cxx -lm -lboost_regex`. It now returns a new, but very lengthy error (which is too long to copy and paste). The boost/regex.hpp is definitely in the path `usr/local/boost_1_64_0`.

Comment: @JohnG: If the error `fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory` is gone, you should accept this answer and submit another question with your new error message....the fact that `boost/regex.hpp` was your original question and it is now answered.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.